# CAndroid animation elastic effect on image dragged left or right

Tags: java, android, android-layout, android-fragments, android-animation

I am new to android,

I have six images in a fragment which is in a scrollview, one over the other,like a stack.

Objective :

1. User should be able to add remove item in the basket.
2. User drags item to the right of the screen item is added to the basket, and images comes back to its position.
3. User drags item to the left of the screen item is removed of the bucket, and images comes back to its position.

I will be able to handle, putting item into the basket etc, only thing which I am curious is **drag elastic effect**, and I am sure there must be some way to achieve it.

I will really appreciate if someone point/show me a way to achieve it.

This is what I am trying to achieve. Pulling/dragging image right, adds item to basket
[image]

By pulling/dragging image left removes item from the basket.
[image]

Thanks,
Shashank

[1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SmkIa.png):

Comment: No one here to help new people trying to learn android. I am not asking for complete code to help. Just point me a direction using English sentences.

Comment: Or may be, is there any other way, to provide an easy interface, where user can easily add and remove from the bucket.

Comment: @Der Gol...lum , possibly you have some light to show.

Comment: I am also thinking of zoom effect, when user clicks on image, Image zooms, giving user an intuition that item is added, I am not able think of removing it... as user can add multiple pieces of each item.

Comment: Its already been asked before. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4139288/android-how-to-handle-right-to-left-swipe-gestures

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Its already been asked before here, it might help someone.

[Android: How to handle right to left swipe gestures](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4139288/android-how-to-handle-right-to-left-swipe-gestures)